Is it possible to move partitions around on Mac OS using dd and gdisk?
Please bare with me, if this question seems dumb. I'm not experienced with filesystems and partitions.
I have an IMG file from a 16GB sd card. My issue is: I have a 32GB sd card and do not want 16GB to be unavailable when putting the image to my card. So my aim ist to extend the last partition to fill the rest of the card.
Would this one partition be the last one, it wouldn't be an issue. Unfortunately it's the first.
Current layout is this:
Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1           73728         8880127   4.2 GiB     0700  Roms
   2         8880128         8945663   32.0 MiB    0700  boot-resource
   3         8945664         8978431   16.0 MiB    0700  env
   4         8978432         9109503   64.0 MiB    0700  boot
   5         9109504        25886719   8.0 GiB     0700  rootfs
   6        25886720        30373887   2.1 GiB     0700  UDISK

I would like to have the Roms partition to be at the end, So I guess the layout would be like:
Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1           73728          139263   32.0 MiB    0700  boot-resource
   2          139264          172031   16.0 MiB    0700  env
   3          172032          303103   64.0 MiB    0700  boot
   4          303104        17080319   8.0 GiB     0700  rootfs
   5        17080320        21567487   2.1 GiB     0700  UDISK
   6        21567488        30373887   4.2 GiB     0700  Roms

The Content of the Roms partition needs not be preserved, but the others must move.
Is there a way I can move all the current partitions' content?
I'm using a Mac and have gdisk (from Homebrew) installed.

To answer my own question: Yes, you can.
This is what I did:
Create a dump of each partition and of the stuff before and after it:
dd                  count=73728  bs=512 if=ORIGINAL.IMG status=progress of=aa.img 
dd    skip=73728  count=8806400  bs=512 if=ORIGINAL.IMG status=progress of=roms.img
dd  skip=8880128    count=65536  bs=512 if=ORIGINAL.IMG status=progress of=boot-resource.img
dd  skip=8945664    count=32768  bs=512 if=ORIGINAL.IMG status=progress of=env.img
dd  skip=8978432   count=131072  bs=512 if=ORIGINAL.IMG status=progress of=boot.img
dd  skip=9109504 count=16777216  bs=512 if=ORIGINAL.IMG status=progress of=rootfs.img
dd skip=25886720  count=4487168  bs=512 if=ORIGINAL.IMG status=progress of=UDISK.img
dd skip=30373888                 bs=512 if=ORIGINAL.IMG status=progress of=zz.img

Then rearrange using cat:
cat -u aa.img boot-resource.img env.img boot.img rootfs.img UDISK.img Roms.img zz.img > sorted.img

Calculate the new partition positions:



Partition
Start (sector)
End (sector)
Name




1
21567488
30373887
Roms


2
73728
139263
boot-resource


3
139264
172031
env


4
172032
303103
boot


5
303104
17080319
rootfs


6
17080320
21567487
UDISK



Then go into gdisk, delete all partitions and recreate them with the calculated sectors.
I kept the Partitionnumbers the same as before. I'm not sure whether or not it's required, but it worked that way.

  "Command" sequence for gdisk I used
  d
  1
  d
  2
  d
  3
  d
  4
  d
  5
  d
  6
  n
  1
  21567488

  0700
  c
  Roms
  n
  2
  73728
  139263
  0700
  c
  2
  boot-resource
  n
  3
  139264
  172031
  0700
  c
  3
  env
  n
  4
  172032
  303103
  0700
  c
  4
  boot
  n
  5
  303104
  17080319
  0700
  c
  5
  rootfs
  n
  6
  17080320
  21567487
  0700
  c
  6
  UDISK

